# Биндинг и значения в PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Первый вопрос по коду:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `guests`";
    if ($STH = $pdo->query($sql)) {
        if ($STH->fetchColumn() > 0) {
            echo "Есть данные";
        }
        else {
            echo "Нет данных";
        }
    }
```

Я туплю и никак не могу понять как мне получить объект или переменную непосредственно с количеством строк, т.е. сколько их 10, 20, 30?

Второй вопрос: почему первый вариант работает, а второй где я пытаюсь биндить параметры не работает. И почему работает первый вариант ведь в нём нет $value->execute();

Первый

```
$value = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `guests` WHERE id=7 ");
if($Row = $value->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($Row);
}
```

Второй

```
$id = 7;
$value = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `guests` WHERE id=:id ");
$value->bindParam(":id",$id);
if($Row = $value->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($Row);
}
```

Comment: `почему первый вариант работает, а второй где я пытаюсь биндить параметры не работает. И почему работает первый вариант ведь в нём нет $value->execute();` - таки просто надо почитать документацию, не? второй не работает потому что надо правильно биндить (**prepare-bindParam/bindValue-execute**)  **http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php**...... первый работает потому что PDO::query — Выполняет SQL запрос и возвращает результирующий набор в виде объекта PDOStatement  **http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php**  ....

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский я вас понял а по первому вопросу подскажете?

Comment: Но ведь в  **[примерах в документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchcolumn-examples)**  всё написано...... ну вот правда... положи полученные данные в переменную (например $result ) и пользуйся ей.... только в ней в итоге будет то, что ты и выбрал `$result['COUNT(*)']` .... если хочешь нормально имя, типа `$result['rec_count']`, то и в запросе надо будет давать псевдоним `SELECT COUNT(*) as rec_count FROM `guests`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Второй" вариант - это вы пытаетесь использовать подготовленный запрос. Делается это так:

```
$id = 7;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `guests` WHERE id=:id ");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$stmt->execute();

if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Про количества строк. По умолчанию PDO работает с курсором в БД и до момента извлечения всех строк их количество(в большинстве случаев) неизвестно. Вы можете использовать, например, [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php) и работать с результирующим набором как с массивом